# Certificate Chain does not work in mockserver

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, tls1.2, mockserver

I would use a Certificate Chain (multiple PEM file merged in one file - end-entity certificate + Intermediate certificate) to do server authentication.
I'm using the following env variable:

```
MOCKSERVER_TLS_X509_CERTIFICATE_PATH
```

pointing to a file with multiple certificates inside.

The mockserver shows the following error:

```
2022-05-06 13:40:57 5.11.2 FINE using command line options:

serverPort=1080

2022-05-06 13:41:00 5.11.2 INFO created expectation file watcher for

2022-05-06 13:41:03 5.11.2 FINE logger level is DEBUG, change using:

'ConfigurationProperties.logLevel(String level)' in Java code,
'-logLevel' command line argument,
'mockserver.logLevel' JVM system property or,
'mockserver.logLevel' property value in 'mockserver.properties'
2022-05-06 13:41:03 5.11.2 INFO 1080 started on port: 1080
2022-05-06 13:41:20 5.11.2 SEVERE TSL handshake failure while a client attempted to connect to [id: 0xad8bc00f, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:1080]
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Insufficient buffer remaining for AEAD cipher fragment (2). Needs to be more than tag size (16)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:471)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Insufficient buffer remaining for AEAD cipher fragment (2). Needs to be more than tag size (16)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:320)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:129)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:668)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:623)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:441)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:420)
at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:634)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:282)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1387)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1282)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1329)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440)
... 16 more
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Insufficient buffer remaining for AEAD cipher fragment (2). Needs to be more than tag size (16)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher$T13GcmReadCipherGenerator$GcmReadCipher.decrypt(SSLCipher.java:1868)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLEngineInputRecord.java:240)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineInputRecord.decode(SSLEngineInputRecord.java:197)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineInputRecord.decode(SSLEngineInputRecord.java:160)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:108)
... 27 more
```

when I perform the following curl:

```
curl -L https://localhost:1080 --cacert rest-ms-certs/myRootCA.pem -v
```

the output of curl is:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1:1080...
TCP_NODELAY set
Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 1080 (#0)
ALPN, offering h2
ALPN, offering http/1.1
successfully set certificate verify locations:
CAfile: rest-ms-certs/myRootCA.pem
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unsupported certificate (555):
SSL certificate problem: unsupported certificate purpose
Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unsupported certificate purpose
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```